# Why does a certain integral on a 3-manifold depend only on its boundary data?

Tags: manifolds-with-boundary, topological-quantum-field-theory

I am reading Dan Freed's lectures on [Quantum Groups on Path Integrals](https://arxiv.org/pdf/q-alg/9501025.pdf). I am picking up the required math as I go along and I am finding certain calculations hard to follow.

This is regarding the discussion on page 7. We have the following setup:

A two dimensional closed oriented manifold $X$,  a Lie group $G=SU(2)$, a smooth map $\phi: X\to G$ and a $3$-form $\omega$ on $G$ with the property that $\int_X \omega = 1$.

Now the map $\phi$ is extended to a map $\Phi:W \to G$ where $W$ is a oriented three manifold whose boundary is $X$ and the restriction of $\Phi$ on the boundary is $\phi$. We define a functional $$S(\Phi) = \int_W \Phi^* \omega.$$

Apparently it is "straightforward" to see that if we choose a different pair $(\Phi, W)$, the functional differs by an integer. Why is this so?